# how can i test browser back-button behaviour using jest and (react-) testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working on a React app, using Jest and [Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) for my tests. I'd like to test what happens when the user clicks the browser's back button. Is that possible, and if so, how? I know I could use Cypress but I'd prefer to avoid adding that to my project.

Comment: probably there is no way: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2112 Would be happy to be wrong on that.

Comment: First of all, do you want unit test or e2e test? Second, provide the code you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React Router, first you need access to the history object in your test and then you can call [history.goBack()](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history).

There are a few options to get the history object:

1. [From a custom route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing/checking-location-in-tests)

```
<Route
  path="*"
  render={props => {
     history = props.history;
     location = props.location;
     return null;
  }}
/>
```

2. [Using createMemoryHistory](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router)

```js
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
...
const history = createMemoryHistory()
...
<Router history={history}>
```